# AngularUI Typeahead + Model value change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a textbox for which i suggest cities. I have used angualar-ui typeahead for suggestions. Now everything seems to be working fine.

Just that when i reset form through angular using $scope.cancel it does not reflect on UI and also the model does not seem to be reset to correct value since the form seems to be dirty. For fields that are not having typeahead works just fine.

Anyone came across this?

Code:

```
<input placeholder='City' type="text" ng-model="form.city" typeahead="x for x in suggestCity($viewValue)" />

function ContactController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $scope.form = angular.copy($scope.userprofile.contact);
    }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/JuIuAXZQVsJlEzjM0faT?p=preview

Comment: could you share your complete html or fiddle code please

Comment: edited question to add plnkr code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so there was a bug fixed in the 0.4.0 version of http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

The change done in https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/591 fixes your issue as well. It wasn't released yet but here is the working plunk with the version from continuous integration server:

http://plnkr.co/edit/17UOgHJd82otwC6TS7s9?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot :) is there a way i can get hold of the fix? or should i wait for the release? any idea when this wil be released?

Comment: You can always get the latest version from the GitHub repository or the CI server (link in plunker). Next release will be in 3 weeks time.